# Still having issues deploying flask app on Godaddy shared hosting

Tags: python, .htaccess, flask, cgi, shared-hosting

I've been trying now for some time to deploy my flask app on a Godaddy hosting server. I have done extensive searches online and followed them but I'm still having issues. Right now my app is just displaying as ordinary html so I'm having things like {{my_var}} displayed on the page. My flask app works locally and this is the folder structure;

**myApp** folder, which contains **static** folder for css,javascript, and images, **templates** folder for my html, and the myapp.py and forms.py files come under the myApp folder

On my hosting server my folder structure is currently this; **$HOME/public_html** which contains the index.html and base.html (index.html inherits from this file for the header and footers), **$HOME/public_html/cgi-bin** which contains myapp.cgi, myapp.py, and .htaccess files.

I've created a cgi file and made it executable which is saved in the public_html/cgi-bin folder. The file is also made executable with 755 permission. These are the contents;

```
#!/home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/flask_app/bin/python
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from myapp import app
import os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

os.environ["SERVER_NAME"] = "127.0.0.1"
os.environ["SERVER_PORT"] = "4000"
os.environ["REQUEST_METHOD"] = "GET"
os.environ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] = "http/1.1"

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

Note the shebang on my files is the path to my virtualenv where I have flask installed. The version of python is v2.7
I also have my main flask app (myapp.py which is also executable and with 755 permissions) file with the routes and the contents are as follows;

```
#!/home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/flask_app/bin/python
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/aofadero/public_html/cgi-bin')#path to myapp.py

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This file is also in my public_html/cgi-bin folder. I also have a .htaccess file which has the following content;

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/myapp.cgi)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/myapp.cgi/$1 [L]
```

Now this .htaccess file is currently in my public_html/cgi-bin folder because if I place it in public_html folder, I get a 500 error message. The only time I don't get the error is when the .htaccess file is in the cgi-bin folder. Some of the research I've done say to place it in the cgi-bin folder, others say in the public_html folder. I find that it only works for me when it's in the cgi-bin folder. If I do ./myapp.cgi I get the following error;

```
Status: 404 NOT FOUND
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 233

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>...
```

Can anyone help me please because I've tried about everything I could on my own. Right now I'm just getting ordinary html and none of the flask components are showing. Thanks

Comment: Anyone not able to help??

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problems. I understand that an **index.htm** file must be placed at **public_html**, but when you try to do **render_template("index.htm")**, Flask will look for this file in the **templates** folder. The rendering is not actually executed. The **index.htm** file will always be displayed on the browser as a default page. Have you been able to find the solution ?

Comment: I'm afraid I've not been able to find a solution to this yet. I was hoping someone else might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include the Python script in the public_html. If you go to the Cpanel main page and search for Python. From there, you can create a Python app which will let you direct your website to run the Python script.

Application root = path to the folder your python is stored. I stored mine in a Python folder in the root of the private html.

Application url = what URL should you need to put into the browser to get that script.

Application startup file = The name of your Python script.

Application Entry point = The callable object in your Python script (in your case, it would be app).

Please see the video here for a walkthrough of this process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFxL7Mvut6g&ab_channel=Hob-iZadeAdemEfendi